# Does the JVM JIT optimises the creation of new objects that are almost equal?

Tags: java, jit, functional-java

I was reading the source code of the Functional Java library and noticed this:

```
public static <T> Option<T> none() {
    return new None<T>();
}
```

I was wondering why they don't always return a singleton parameter, specially because of None's equality implementation:

```
private static final class None<A> extends Option<A> { 

...

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (this == obj)
      return true;
   if (obj == null)
      return false;
   if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
   return true;
}

}
```

So I did a search at Functional Java's forum and I found this question and answer:

> Is it possible to set this up so it doesn't create a new None for every call to none, can we use a single object to represent  None in all cases?
>
> No, but then, who cares? The JIT optimiser can take care of these things quite well nowadays.

My question is how the JIT optimiser handles this in a way that it isn't necessary to return a singleton. I know that object creation is cheap, but I think a singleton would be cheaper and in this case it doesn't add any complexity.

Comment: I don't think they meant to imply the JVM would re-use an instance; a `new` is a `new`. A singleton might be *very* marginally faster, but I'd be surprised if it was a gating issue performance-wise in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Java VMs I know don't perfom such optimizations. With modern JVMs it's actually cheaper to create new object rather then look for some existing one. What they also mean in this FAQ is that short-lived, throw-away objects don't really impact garbage collection time (but might increase GC frequency). Also I can imagine JVM performing escape analysis and allocating such object on stack rather than on heap.

However I *do* think it's quite wasteful. Look at `java.lang.Integer` (and all other primitive wrappers) cache or [`Optional.absent()` in Guava](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/13.0.1/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#Optional.absent%28%29):

```
public static <T> Optional<T> absent() {
  return (Optional<T>) Absent.INSTANCE;
}
```

There are plenty of other optimizations like that in the JDK: `enum`s are singletons, [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.emptyList%28%29) always returns the same instance, etc.

Comment: I can see how a new object might be faster than retrieving a singleton instance. Consider that new instance could be created in cache memory while retrieving a singleton needs to go to main memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is more type safe, otherwise we need to rely on erasure.

Creating an object is probably still more expensive than looking up a cached one. See java8's Optional:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/ad394630273b/src/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java

```
   43     private final static Optional<?> EMPTY = new Optional<>();

   63      * There is no guarantee that it is a singleton.

   69     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   70     public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
   71         return (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
   72     }
```